# how to edit this updateer_script?

Tags: custom-roms

I have a custom Rom For Samsung GT-S7582. 
When I try to install it through CWM recovery it gives **status 7** error. 
So I followed this thread [To remove status 7 error](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2302599) on XDA

But still it won't install. Can someone help me how to edit this this file. 
My file is as follows

```
assert(getprop("ro.product.device") == "kyleprods" || getprop("ro.build.product") == "kyleprods" || getprop("ro.product.device") == "S7582" || getprop("ro.build.product") == "S7582" || getprop("ro.product.device") == "GT-S7582" || getprop("ro.build.product") == "GT-S7582" || getprop("ro.product.device") == "hawaii" || getprop("ro.build.product") == "hawaii" || getprop("ro.product.device") == "kylexx" || getprop("ro.build.product") == "kylexx" || abort("This package is for device: kyleprods,S7582,GT-S7582,hawaii,kylexx; this device is "   getprop("ro.product.device")   "."););
ifelse(is_mounted("/system"), unmount("/system"));
package_extract_dir("install", "/tmp/install");
set_metadata_recursive("/tmp/install", "uid", 0, "gid", 0, "dmode", 0755, "fmode", 0644);
set_metadata_recursive("/tmp/install/bin", "uid", 0, "gid", 0, "dmode", 0755, "fmode", 0755);
mount("ext4", "EMMC", "/dev/block/platform/sdhci.1/by-name/system", "/system", "");
run_program("/tmp/install/bin/backuptool.sh", "backup");
unmount("/system");
if is_mounted("/data") then
package_extract_file("META-INF/org/cyanogenmod/releasekey", "/tmp/releasekey");
run_program("/tmp/install/bin/otasigcheck.sh") != "31744" || abort("Can't install this package on top of incompatible data. Please try another package or run a factory reset");
else
mount("ext4", "EMMC", "/dev/block/platform/sdhci.1/by-name/userdata", "/data", "");
package_extract_file("META-INF/org/cyanogenmod/releasekey", "/tmp/releasekey");
run_program("/tmp/install/bin/otasigcheck.sh") != "31744" || abort("Can't install this package on top of incompatible data. Please try another package or run a factory reset");
unmount("/data");
endif;
show_progress(0.750000, 0);
ui_print("Patching system image unconditionally...");
block_image_update("/dev/block/platform/sdhci.1/by-name/system", package_extract_file("system.transfer.list"), "system.new.dat", "system.patch.dat");
show_progress(0.020000, 10);
mount("ext4", "EMMC", "/dev/block/platform/sdhci.1/by-name/system", "/system", "");
run_program("/tmp/install/bin/backuptool.sh", "restore");
unmount("/system");
show_progress(0.050000, 5);
package_extract_file("boot.img", "/dev/block/platform/sdhci.1/by-name/KERNEL");
show_progress(0.200000, 10);
```

Comment: So you have deleted the assert prop line? "But still it won't install. " - Still the status 7 error? "ifelse(is_mounted("/system"), unmount" should be the start of the file

Comment: It doesn't give status 7 error. 
But won't install

Comment: any error message during the installation process? Which editor did you use to edit the file? Did you build the custom rom yourself or where did you get it from? A little more information would be good :)

Comment: Got Rom from this site 
http://forum.cyanogenmod.org/topic/116672-romunofficialstablecm121galaxy-trend-plus-s-duos-2-gt-s7580-gt-s7582/
I was trying to install with cwm it wasn't working so I flashed TWRP but still both zips won't flash

Comment: Ok let's sum this up. You are using a Samsung GT-S7582? You flashed the rom through CWM and received a Status 7 error - then flashed TWRP and it didn't change anything? Again: **Which editor are you using** to edit the updater-script? You have deleted the first line, saved and replaced the updater-script in the zip file? Which error are you getting when flashing now? "wasn't working" is not precise enough - please [edit](http://android.stackexchange.com/posts/131680/edit) your question and include the information and say which steps you have followed successfully and which were not successfull

Comment: thanks for replying..
It worked with latest TWRP.
using new ROM now